# Unable to run Application Module Tester in Jdev 12c

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Using MySQL DB, I made some EO and VO's in Jdev 12c - 12.2.1.0.0.

When I right click on AM and run, then it shows the following error

```
oracle.jbo.jbotester.app.ErrorHandler$ExceptionWrapper: JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: oracle.jbo.DMLException, msg=JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC connection.
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.app.ErrorHandler.displayError(ErrorHandler.java:108)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.app.ErrorHandler.displayError(ErrorHandler.java:94)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.app.IErrorHandlerImpl.displayError(IErrorHandlerImpl.java:43)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:513)
Caused by: oracle.jbo.DMLException: JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC connection.
  at oracle.jbo.server.URLConnectionHelper.getConnection(URLConnectionHelper.java:218)
  at oracle.jbo.server.URLConnectionHelper.getConnection(URLConnectionHelper.java:45)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ConnectionPoolDataSource.getConnection(ConnectionPoolDataSource.java:75)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.establishNewConnection(DBTransactionImpl.java:999)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.initTransaction(DBTransactionImpl.java:1184)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.initTxn(DBTransactionImpl.java:7115)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl2.connectToDataSource(DBTransactionImpl2.java:297)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl2.connectToDataSource(DBTransactionImpl2.java:328)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.DefaultConnectionStrategy.connect(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:203)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.doPoolConnect(ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.java:643)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.doPoolMessage(ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.java:439)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleImpl.doPoolMessage(ApplicationModuleImpl.java:9909)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.sendPoolMessage(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:4538)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.prepareApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2453)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.doCheckout(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2263)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.useApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:3162)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:604)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:537)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:532)
  at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.initializeApplicationModule(DCJboDataControl.java:644)
  at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.getApplicationModule(DCJboDataControl.java:1017)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.binding.TesterBinding.getConnectionInfo(TesterBinding.java:100)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.initializeDataControl(MainFrame.java:1054)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.loadConfiguration(MainFrame.java:697)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.processArgs(MainFrame.java:674)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:501)
## Detail 0 ##
oracle.jbo.DMLException: JBO-26061: Error while opening JDBC connection.
  at oracle.jbo.server.URLConnectionHelper.getConnection(URLConnectionHelper.java:218)
  at oracle.jbo.server.URLConnectionHelper.getConnection(URLConnectionHelper.java:45)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ConnectionPoolDataSource.getConnection(ConnectionPoolDataSource.java:75)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.establishNewConnection(DBTransactionImpl.java:999)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.initTransaction(DBTransactionImpl.java:1184)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl.initTxn(DBTransactionImpl.java:7115)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl2.connectToDataSource(DBTransactionImpl2.java:297)
  at oracle.jbo.server.DBTransactionImpl2.connectToDataSource(DBTransactionImpl2.java:328)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.DefaultConnectionStrategy.connect(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:203)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.doPoolConnect(ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.java:643)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.doPoolMessage(ApplicationPoolMessageHandler.java:439)
  at oracle.jbo.server.ApplicationModuleImpl.doPoolMessage(ApplicationModuleImpl.java:9909)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.sendPoolMessage(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:4538)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.prepareApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2453)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.doCheckout(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:2263)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl.useApplicationModule(ApplicationPoolImpl.java:3162)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:604)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:537)
  at oracle.jbo.common.ampool.SessionCookieImpl.useApplicationModule(SessionCookieImpl.java:532)
  at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.initializeApplicationModule(DCJboDataControl.java:644)
  at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.getApplicationModule(DCJboDataControl.java:1017)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.binding.TesterBinding.getConnectionInfo(TesterBinding.java:100)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.initializeDataControl(MainFrame.java:1054)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.loadConfiguration(MainFrame.java:697)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.processArgs(MainFrame.java:674)
  at oracle.jbo.jbotester.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:501)
```

The same runs fine in Jdev 11g.
A similar question was there in Oracle ADF community but it is not answered

Comment: Please check this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/121300-cert-2164864.html It shows the supported versions of MySQL (and other techs). Verify if you version is supported.

Comment: @User404 Hi, Yes My JDK is 1.8 and MySQL 5.6.x, both are supported. Tried changing MySQL driver but issue persists.